# How To Access a jupyter Notebook cell using a button click?

Tags: python, button, automation, jupyter-notebook, cell

Can I access  Jupyter Notebook Cell using tkinter desktop application ? OR Can I past code in a cell on a button click ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a module called `subprocess` which you can use to open jupyter notebook along with tkinter. Look at this code -

```
import tkinter as tk
import subprocess

root = tk.Tk()

root.title('Jupyter Notebook')

def open_jup():
    p = subprocess.Popen(["start", "cmd", "/k", "jupyter notebook"], shell = True)


button = tk.Button(root,text='OPEN Jupyter Notebook',command=open_jup)
button.pack(fill='both')


root.mainloop()
```

`Subprocess.Popen` will open the cmd and run the `jupyter notebook` and then,
this will open the jupyter notebook in the browser
This worked for me ! It can take some time the first time you run this.